# Any config to import in single quote after refactoring typescript in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an enum `AnEnum` in a typescript file. There're 3 references to `AnEnum`.

I use the refactor feature in VS Code: highlight the enum, click the light bulb, choose "Move to a new file". The enum `AnEnum` was moved to a new file and also updated the imports in the above 3 references. Therefore, it updated the imports link as double quotes while I expect the single quote.

Is there any configuration to resolve that?